ReadTimeoutError between Selenium and Chromedriver in AWS Synthentic canaries
I have a set of Selenium tests running in AWS Synthetic canaries. I recently upgraded the runtime the canaries use from syn-python-selenium-2.1 to syn-python-selenium-4.0 and the tests have started hitting sporadic, but frequent failures where the connectivity between Selenium and Chromedriver appears to drop.
I have enabled various bits of logging and would like help trying to interpret what the logs are showing. I have copied some more detailed snippets from the logs at the bottom. The selenium logs don't appear to reveal anything interesting to me, however urllib3 shows the following happening:
2024-08-08 19:16:13,590 DEBUG: Incremented Retry for (url='/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2024-08-08 19:16:13,591 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=60503): Read timed out. (read timeout=61)")': /session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled

Once this has occurred, no further Selenium commands work - they all timeout or error in some way.
From the Chrome and Chromedriver logs, neither of these seem to crash or error at that point in time. Am I correct in saying this means the connectivity between selenium/urllib3 and Chromedriver running on localhost port 60503 breaks down at this point?
My instinct is that the new chrome-headless-shell binary is somehow involved as that was the only obvious significant change AWS made in syn-python-selenium-4.0 vs 2.1, but I'm unclear how that could be.
Does anyone have any advice about how to proceed or what more could be investigated? Thanks for any help!
Selenium logs
2024-08-08 19:15:11,863 DEBUG: POST http://localhost:60503/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element {'using': 'css selector', 'value': '[id="id_deliver_report_btn"]'}
2024-08-08 19:15:11,885 DEBUG: Remote response: status=200 | data={"value":{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722"}} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '127', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
2024-08-08 19:15:11,885 DEBUG: Finished Request
2024-08-08 19:15:11,885 DEBUG: POST http://localhost:60503/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/execute/sync {'script': '/* isDisplayed */return (function(){return (function(){var g=this||self;\nfunction aa(a){var b=typeof...', 'args': [{'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722'}]}
2024-08-08 19:15:11,907 DEBUG: Remote response: status=200 | data={"value":true} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '14', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
2024-08-08 19:15:11,907 DEBUG: Finished Request
2024-08-08 19:15:11,908 DEBUG: GET http://localhost:60503/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled {}
2024-08-08 19:15:11,926 DEBUG: Remote response: status=200 | data={"value":true} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '14', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
2024-08-08 19:15:11,926 DEBUG: Finished Request
2024-08-08 19:15:11,926 DEBUG: GET http://localhost:60503/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled {}
2024-08-08 19:15:11,932 DEBUG: Remote response: status=200 | data={"value":true} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '14', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
2024-08-08 19:15:11,932 DEBUG: Finished Request
2024-08-08 19:15:11,932 DEBUG: POST http://localhost:60503/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/click {}
2024-08-08 19:15:12,005 DEBUG: Remote response: status=200 | data={"value":null} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '14', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
2024-08-08 19:15:12,006 DEBUG: Finished Request
2024-08-08 19:15:12,006 DEBUG: GET http://localhost:60503/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled {}
2024-08-08 19:15:12,027 DEBUG: Remote response: status=200 | data={"value":false} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '15', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
2024-08-08 19:15:12,027 DEBUG: Finished Request
2024-08-08 19:15:12,528 DEBUG: GET http://localhost:60503/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled {}
2024-08-08 19:17:14,654 DEBUG: POST http://localhost:60503/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/execute/sync {'script': 'return document.documentElement.outerHTML', 'args': []}

urllib3 logs
2024-08-08 19:15:11,862 DEBUG: http://localhost:60503 "POST /session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/execute/sync HTTP/1.1" 200 31
2024-08-08 19:15:11,884 DEBUG: http://localhost:60503 "POST /session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element HTTP/1.1" 200 127
2024-08-08 19:15:11,907 DEBUG: http://localhost:60503 "POST /session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/execute/sync HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2024-08-08 19:15:11,925 DEBUG: http://localhost:60503 "GET /session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2024-08-08 19:15:11,932 DEBUG: http://localhost:60503 "GET /session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2024-08-08 19:15:12,005 DEBUG: http://localhost:60503 "POST /session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/click HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2024-08-08 19:15:12,026 DEBUG: http://localhost:60503 "GET /session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled HTTP/1.1" 200 15
2024-08-08 19:16:13,590 DEBUG: Incremented Retry for (url='/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2024-08-08 19:16:13,591 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=60503): Read timed out. (read timeout=61)")': /session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/element/f.8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396.d.BCFB2DDB752682B894CDCEAE0060D046.e.722/enabled
2024-08-08 19:16:13,591 DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (2): localhost:60503
2024-08-08 19:17:14,655 DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (3): localhost:60503
2024-08-08 19:18:15,718 DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (4): localhost:60503
2024-08-08 19:19:16,781 DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (5): localhost:60503
2024-08-08 19:20:17,844 DEBUG: Incremented Retry for (url='/session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/url'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2024-08-08 19:20:17,844 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=60503): Read timed out. (read timeout=61)")': /session/d2fce95c49c29f09a04300b98b19fa52/url

Chrome logs
[0808/191512.001895:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/api/v2/study/370973/analysis/343494/analysis_report/156963/deliver/
[0808/191512.195147:VERBOSE1:back_forward_cache_impl.cc(725)] BackForwardCacheImpl::GetFutureBackForwardCacheEligibilityPotential: https://portal.**********.com/view/370973/analysis/343494 : No: BackForwardCache is not supported by delegate
[0808/191512.195179:VERBOSE1:back_forward_cache_impl.cc(725)] BackForwardCacheImpl::GetCompleteBackForwardCacheEligibilityForReporting: https://portal.**********.com/view/370973/analysis/343494 : No: BackForwardCache is not supported by delegate
[0808/191512.195942:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/view/370973/analysis/343494?tab=reports
[0808/191512.382052:VERBOSE1:back_forward_cache_impl.cc(725)] BackForwardCacheImpl::GetFutureBackForwardCacheEligibilityPotential: https://portal.**********.com/view/370973/analysis/343494 : No: BackForwardCache is not supported by delegate
[0808/191512.382090:VERBOSE1:back_forward_cache_impl.cc(725)] BackForwardCacheImpl::GetCompleteBackForwardCacheEligibilityForReporting: https://portal.**********.com/view/370973/analysis/343494 : No: BackForwardCache is not supported by delegate
[0808/191512.386472:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://col.site24x7rum.eu/rum/trace
[0808/191512.387951:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://col.site24x7rum.eu/rum/wcv
[0808/191512.403232:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/localise.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.421399:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/jsi18n/
[0808/191512.646039:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://static.site24x7rum.eu/beacon/site24x7rum-min.js?appKey=2afbfd621b81476d3ee6b72522e7325b
[0808/191512.701097:INFO:CONSOLE(24)] "You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/", source: https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js (24)
[0808/191512.721499:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/react/utils.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.721739:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/react/StepBar.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.721907:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/react/incidentalFindingsModal.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.722207:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/localise.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.722594:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/react/view_analysis/dataFilesApp.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.723427:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/react/view_analysis/reportsApp.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.723679:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/react/view_analysis/rejectionReportsApp.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.724175:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/react/linksApp.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.724344:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/react/summaryApp.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.724507:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/react/comment.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.724661:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://portal.**********.com/static/js/react/view_study/filesTabApp.js?v=v6.10.3
[0808/191512.801367:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://col.site24x7rum.eu/rum/data

Chromedriver logs
[1723144512.802][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Network.responseReceived (session_id=E997E753EA90A061F6B711C5598C65DB) 8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396 {
   "frameId": "8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396",
   "hasExtraInfo": false,
   "loaderId": "249E481227E62BBD19999E2D230A440C",
   "requestId": "17.1877",
   "response": {
      "alternateProtocolUsage": "unspecifiedReason",
      "charset": "",
      "connectionId": 0,
      "connectionReused": false,
      "encodedDataLength": 0,
      "fromDiskCache": true,
      "fromPrefetchCache": false,
      "fromServiceWorker": false,
      "headers": {
         "content-encoding": "gzip",
         "content-type": "application/javascript",
         "date": "Thu, 08 Aug 2024 19:13:06 GMT",
         "etag": "W/\"66b3dbf2-3b44\"",
         "last-modified": "Wed, 07 Aug 2024 20:41:22 GMT",
         "server": "nginx",
         "vary": "Accept-Encoding"
      },
      "mimeType": "application/javascript",
      "protocol": "h2",
      "remoteIPAddress": "23.20.119.29",
      "remotePort": 443,
      "responseTime": 1.723144386184758e+12,
      "securityDetails": {
         "certificateId": 0,
         "certificateTransparencyCompliance": "unknown",
         "cipher": "AES_128_GCM",
         "encryptedClientHello": false,
         "issuer": "Amazon RSA 2048 M03",
         "keyExchange": "ECDHE_RSA",
         "keyExchangeGroup": "P-256",
         "protocol": "TLS 1.2",
         "sanList": [ "*.**********.com" ],
         "serverSignatureAlgorithm": 1025,
         "signedCertificateTimestampList": [  ],
         "subjectName": "*.**********.com",
         "validFrom": 1713657600,
         "validTo": 1747699199
      },
      "securityState": "secure",
      "status": 200,
      "statusText": "",
      "timing": {
         "connectEnd": -1,
         "connectStart": -1,
         "dnsEnd": -1,
         "dnsStart": -1,
         "proxyEnd": -1,
         "proxyStart": -1,
         "pushEnd": 0,
         "pushStart": 0,
         "receiveHeadersEnd": 39.451,
         "receiveHeadersStart": 1.249,
         "requestTime": 8416.062898,
         "sendEnd": 0.219,
         "sendStart": 0.219,
         "sslEnd": -1,
         "sslStart": -1,
         "workerFetchStart": -1,
         "workerReady": -1,
         "workerRespondWithSettled": -1,
         "workerStart": -1
      },
      "~~~": "..."
   },
   "timestamp": 8416.141347,
   "type": "XHR"
}
[1723144512.802][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Network.dataReceived (session_id=E997E753EA90A061F6B711C5598C65DB) 8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396 {
   "dataLength": 15172,
   "encodedDataLength": 0,
   "requestId": "17.1877",
   "timestamp": 8416.141592
}
[1723144512.802][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Network.loadingFinished (session_id=E997E753EA90A061F6B711C5598C65DB) 8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396 {
   "encodedDataLength": 0,
   "requestId": "17.1877",
   "timestamp": 8416.124562
}
[1723144512.802][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Network.dataReceived (session_id=E997E753EA90A061F6B711C5598C65DB) 8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396 {
   "dataLength": 14411,
   "encodedDataLength": 0,
   "requestId": "17.1871",
   "timestamp": 8416.142401
}
[1723144512.927][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Network.responseReceivedExtraInfo (session_id=E997E753EA90A061F6B711C5598C65DB) 8B288A6684E4F6D6F3484B1DEF095396 {
   "blockedCookies": [  ],
   "cookiePartitionKey": "https://**********.com",
   "cookiePartitionKeyOpaque": false,
   "exemptedCookies": [  ],
   "headers": {
      "access-control-allow-headers": "request-id, request-context, Origin, Accept-Language",
      "access-control-allow-methods": "POST,OPTIONS",
      "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
      "content-length": "0",
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1",
      "date": "Thu, 08 Aug 2024 19:15:12 GMT",
      "server": "ZGS",
      "vary": "Origin",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN"
   },
   "requestId": "17.1882",
   "resourceIPAddressSpace": "Public",
   "statusCode": 200
}

Versions Used

Selenium v4.21.0
Chromedriver 126.0.6478.126
Chromium 126.0.6478.126 (with headless-chrome-shell)


Hi -- this is unrelated to your question, but how did you enable ChromeDriver and Chrome logs on your canary? I need to do the same on mine.

Hello. Adding Chrome logs is straightforward.
`chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-logging")
chrome_options.add_argument("--v=1")
os.environ["CHROME_LOG_FILE"] = "/tmp/chrome.log"
driver = synthetics_webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)`
This will output the log into tmp, so the canary will store it in the corresponding test artefacts S3 bucket at the end of the run. It's much harder to get Chromedriver to log. I had to edit the boilerplate lambda code that AWS internally provides. Wouldn't recommend trying!

Cool, thanks. Did you manage to fix this @Oli? My organisation is experiencing the very challenge you outlined in your original post.

Yeah we’re still seeing them. There is a fix of sorts which is to use syn-python-selenium-2.1 or below if you can. This only seems to affect 3.0 onwards so I have a strong hunch I know the cause, but don’t think we as users can resolve it. The problem started soon after AWS upgraded Chromium beyond v111 which is where headless chrome moved into a separate binary instead of being bundled with the browser. I’m pretty convinced it’s the new binary or the connection between it and Chrome that’s flaky. I can’t use Python 3.8 so I have to live with it and hope a future runtime release fixes it!
